# Using windows forfiles batch to extract audio tracks from webm

Tags: batch-file, webm

I've tried various iterations of the following attempting to extract the audio files from many webm's using mkvextract, I can't see what I am doing wrong.

```
FORFILES /P vid\ /C "cmd /c echo mkvextract tracks @path 2:\processed\@fname.ogg"
FORFILES /P vid\ /C "mkvextract tracks @path 2:\processed\@fname.ogg"
pause
```

My Directory structure

```
|-run.bat    
|-Mkvextract.eve
|-vid
  |-vid 1.webm
  |-vid 2.webm
|-processed
  |-outputgoeshere
```

The path leading to this contains spaces as do the webm files.

MKVExtract documentation: http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvextract.html#mkvextract.escaping

forfiles documentation:
http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this batch file correct the path to `c:\vid` and `mkvextract.exe` and the last term may need modification.  It's worth a try.

```
@echo off
for /r "c:\vid" %%a in (*.webm) do (
   "c:\folder\mkvextract.exe" tracks "%%a" 2:\processed\"%%~nxa.ogg"
)
```

Comment: This worked after slight modification

for /r "C:\<...>\vid" %%a in (*.webm) do (
   "C:\<...>\mkvextract.exe" tracks "%%a" 1:"\processed\%%~nxa.ogg"
)

But ended up dumping everything into C:\processed\ instead of C:\<...>\processed but it got the job done, I guess it was my fault for not specifying my problem more precisely, but thankyou!